# Класс для записи в базу

Tags: c#, база-данных

Есть в базе 3 связанных таблицы. Хочу сделать класс в котором будут переменные с названием всех столбцов из 3 таблиц, и методы которые делали бы выборки и записывали данные в эти переменные. А на форме же эти данные отображались на компонентах. И наоборот при записи данные с формы переносились бы в переменные этого класса и записывались в базу. Это делаю для того что бы в классе проводились еще всякие проверки на null, на соответствие, в некоторых данных значение увеличивалось на 1 (это для Index в ComboBox'е) и т.п.
Вроде как всё сделал:

```
public class PreBlock
{
public int BlockNumber;
public string BlockIndex;
public int BlockMass;
public int Category;
public string CritOtkl;
public string OtklSKP;
//Аппарат востановления
public int VostProcNumber;
public int nCondensat;
public int nVostRetorta;
public int nVostCover;
public int nChvost;
public int nSlivPipe;
// ... и еще много других переменных из таблиц

//метод для выборки по заданому блоку
public void Prepare(int block)
{
//здесь обычная выборка и запись во все вышеперечисленные переменные
}

public void saveBlock
{
//здесь наоборот запись в таблицы по данным из переменных
}
}

//класс формы
public partial class Blocks : Form
{

PreBlock bl; //объект класса
int block;  //номер блока для выборки Prepare
public Blocks()
{
//создаю объект класса и запрос
bl = new PreBlock();
bl.Prepare(block);
//далее уже присваиваю значение компонентам из класса
BlockMass.Value = bl.BlockMass;
Category.Value = bl.Category;
//далее по аналогии присваиваю
}

//перед сохранением присваиваю значение компонентов переменным из класса PreBlock
public void SyncBlock()
{
bl.BlockMass = BlockMass.Value;
bl.Category = Category.Value;
//далее по аналогии присваиваю
//и вот тут возникает ошибка:
//"Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
}
```

Comment: да я опечатался должно быть Blocks(). А метод SyncBlock() я вызываю по кнопке на форме "Сохранить"

Comment: Как это не создался если Blocks() вызывается при создании объекта класса, все нормально, всё вызывается проблема то в методе SyncBlock()

Comment: Вас не смущает то, что вы public методы называете то с большой, то с маленькой буквы? Не говоря уже о public полях, изменение которых может поломать внутренний стейт.

Comment: @Пандакун вы уверены, что класс, моделирующий одновременно три таблицы - это хорошая идея? Если да, то вы уверены, что у вас правильно спроектирована база данных? И вообще, может, имеет смысл воспользоваться ORM?

Comment: block это просто переменная типа int, а в Preblock(block) это просто значение для ключевого поля в выборке, которое связывает все 3 таблицы: SELECT * FROM BlockTg WHERE BlockNumber=block
Просто смешанный запрос из 3 таблиц. 2 из которых по сути просто списки для ComboBox на форме. Да и что с какой буквы начинается на работу не влияет(я понимаю правила хорошего тона и всё такое, но мне же всё понятно тем более я каждый метод комментирую). Не знаю ничего о ORM. У меня просто ошибка при вызове SyncBlock()

Comment: @Пандакун так вы может все-таки покажете код, в котором у вас вываливается исключение? Как я понял, именно его вы почему-то скромно пропустили, написав вместо него этот многозначительный комментарий :

>//далее по аналогии присваиваю
//и вот тут возникает ошибка:
//"Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: Вот http://pastebin.com/gfSMHUS3

Answer (score 4):

Итак, сначала пару слов о коде. Чтобы было понятно, о чем идет речь, [вот он](http://pastebin.com/gfSMHUS3).

Уважаемый [[[[@Пандакун](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD)](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD)](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD)](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD), вы, пожалуйста, не обижайтесь, то, что я скажу ниже, может показаться вам неприятным. Так вот, ваш код отвратителен. В нем вы нарушаете все принципы программирования/проектирования, которые можно нарушить.

Во-первых, вы сваливаете в одну кучу представление, модель и контроллер. (обязательно почитайте про [MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller)). Во-вторых,  У вас в одном классе присутствует и обработка событий, и установка состояний UI, и работа с БД (аж с тремя таблицами) и еще черт знает что (антипаттерн "Божественный объект"), в третьих вы "подавляете" исключение в конструкторе и забиваете сам конструктор тоннами каких-то странных действий. В-четвёртых, вы совершенно забываете об [инкапсуляции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), делая публичными поля класса. В-пятых, у вас неоправданно раздуты методы ваших классов. В-шестых, ужасные идентификаторы - все эти dataReader1 и nVostStove2 со смешением Microsoft- и Java-стилей именования (мелочь с одной стороны, а с другой говорит о вашей неорганизованности)

Что касается ORM - это очень полезная и удобная технология, позволяющая избавиться от ряда проблем, в том числе и ваших.

И конкретно по вашей ошибке. Судя по всему, когда в обращаетесь к BlockText, его не существует. Вероятно, это из-за того, что вы в обработчике события, принадлежащего одной форме, пытаетесь обратиться к элементу BlockText, лежащему на другой. Других внятных причин я этому не вижу, а судить об этом по километровым портянкам кода без обращения к вашему UI  довольно проблематично.

Так или иначе, [[[[@Пандакун](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD)](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD)](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD)](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD), все вышесказанное сказано не с целью сообщить миру о том, какой вы глупый программист, а с целью указать вам на возможные пути улучшения вашего кода, поэтому не воспринимайте это как что-то личное. Вероятно, вы не очень опытный разработчик, поэтому то, о чем я вам говорю, может вам показаться малозначительной чепухой, но, поверьте, это действительно имеет смысл.

Comment: Да нет BlockText то у меня этой же форме. Но проблему решил другим путем. Конструкторе форме создаю экземпляр класса, делаю запрос, заполняю компоненты формы данными. По кнопке сохранить, создаю экземпляр класса (потому что первый исчез по завершении метода), заполняю переменные класса данными, и сохраняю в базу (метод находится в классе Preblock).
Ну да код ужасен, вообще переделывать чужой вдвойне ужасно. Но да ты прав я еще мало знаю, я вообще программировал на Delphi раньше. А о названии переменных, ну не я такие названия придумал -  http://goo.gl/uk5cpt . А научиться бы я хотел конечно.

Comment: Я как то читал про MVC честно говоря мало что понял, и какого нибудь простого примера я то же не нашел. А вот business logic model я понял лучше, я конечно понимаю что у меня её нет. Но я пока что только читал об этом.

Comment: такие вещи лучше даются в сочетании теории с практикой

Comment: Про MVC все так красиво расписано аж страшно стало. Но сомневаюсь что в реальном случае это приживётся, особенно на заводе, где я работаю.  К примеру база над которой сейчас работаю ДО МЕНЯ выглядела вот так - http://goo.gl/8qYfrqИ после того я переделал базу - http://goo.gl/J8yHCM . В некоторых полях вообще через пробел цифры были (это так списки были организованы). Таблица Block вообще тихий ужас - 121 столбец.Так что сейчас еще более менее какая то структура есть. Но до идеала конечно далеко, но это уже клиент надо пилить правильно, а как я не знаю пока что.

Answer (score 3):

Я считаю, что Вам необходимо посмотреть в сторону ORM.
Ваша реализация смешивает логику работы кода, является неоптимальной и наверняка в ней есть куча багов и косяков.
ORM избавит Вас от большинства подобных мелочей (при наличии прямых рук,конечно).
Например, [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb399572.aspx), [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

Comment: Зачем городить огород, там не так уж всё и сложно. Просто смешанный запрос из 3 таблиц. 2 из которых по сути просто списки для ComboBox на форме, так что не думаю что есть смысл строить это, тем более я об этом пока ничего не знаю

Comment: >тем более я об этом пока ничего не знаю

@Пандакун это как раз причина для того, чтобы сделать именно так и тем самым научиться делать правильно, а не "три таблицы в одном классе"

Comment: Дело в том, что Ваш код пригоден только внутри университета, да и то хорошие преподаватели его забракуют. На работе за такое по голове не погладят. Поэтому стоит учиться сразу правильным вещам, как одно из великого множества - ORM.

Comment: @Пандакун: Здесь всё уже сложно. Когда вы пакуете всю сложность в один несчастный класс, у вас (да и ни у кого) _не могут_ поместится в голове все внутренние условия, все правила, что за чем инициализируется и в какой момент на что можно рассчитывать. Если бы было просто, вы не задавали бы вопрос здесь.

Перепишите код на MVC, разбейте на уровни, вот _тогда_ и будет просто. А пока неоправданно сложно.

И да, не жалейте классов. Байты в последнее время подешевели, не жмитесь.

Comment: @VladD забавная ситуация - иллюзорная простота кода, который сложно воспринимать из-за неудачной спроектированности. В итоге с какого-то момента его может понимать только автор

Comment: @DreamChild: Угу, так и есть. Почему-то многие думают, что набросать всё в кучу — это проще. Проще написать — да, проще понять и работать с кодом — отнюдь.

Comment: я уже это где-то слышал: "Когда должен легко читаться, а не писаться"

Comment: @Пандакун: Очень правильно слышали :-) Попробуйте следовать этому.